# Rails ID sequence after csv import in Heroku PG database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, csv, import

I'm building a diary for a user to track his daily expenditures. However, I already have csv file that holds 1751 records that I am importing to my expenditures table. I'm doing this via a rake task.

The import works fine. When I am doing so in development (SQLite) and want to create a new record via the create action the new record holds the ID 1752 (which is correct).

If I do so in production (Heroku/PostgreSQL) Postgres tries to create the new record with ID 1 which, obviously, leads to an error (as the first 1751 IDs are already taken).

My question: how can I fix that so that the Postgres ID sequence starts with ID 1752 instead of ID 1 (like SQLite in development)?

**import_expenditure.rake**

```
require 'csv'

namespace :csv do

  desc "Import CSV Data from Expenditures data"
  task :import_expenditures => :environment do
    Expenditure.delete_all
    csv_file_path = 'db/exp_data.csv'

    CSV.foreach(csv_file_path) do |row|

        Expenditure.create!({
          :id => row[0],
          :day => row[1],
          :value => row[2],  
          :description => row[3],
          :cost_type => row[4],
          :category_id => row[5],
          :user_id => row[6]
        })
        puts "Row added!"

    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this line before the loop

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT setval('expenditures_id_seq', 1752);"
```

This will change the value of `id` column

Comment: Sorry somehow not all of my comment was saved. I want to upload data to the database through a csv import (1751 records to initally fill the database) and then use the app regularly (adding new records through a form in a "new" view) afterwards. However, when I first upload the 1751 records (which produces IDs from 1 to 1751) and after that want to use the standard form to add records, PG tries to save these records starting with ID = 1 (like I would have not uploaded any data before). In development SQLite does add these new records starting with ID 1752.

Comment: I believe your solution (putting the code in the rake) aims at telling PG to start with ID 1752 during import_expenditure.rake is performed, right?

Comment: Yes, so you can just run this after the import